# Customize regular expression to allow alphabets and dots in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello friends
In my application I want to customize regular expression in such a way that it will allow character and dot only. For eg. I could be be able to enter M.C.A or MCA any of these. For this task how to customize regular expression? I tried [a-zA-Z] followed by\ and dot in side bracket but is not working.
I also tried [ABCD] just for testing but it shows invalid text for ABC.
What might be the reason????
Thanks to all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape the dot as in regex it normally means 'any character'

```
[a-zA-Z\.]+
```

in c# you will need to deinfe the regex string as follows:

```
var r = @"[a-zA-Z\.]+";
```

Edit based on comment:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="qualificationBox" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="NameRequiredValidator" runat="server" 
 ErrorMessage="Please Enter Name" ControlToValidate="qualificationBox" 
 ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\.]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the text you are running the regex against?

Comment: @Dve This is the sample of textbox                                    <asp:TextBox ID="qualificationBox" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRequiredValidator" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please Enter Name" ControlToValidate="qualificationBox"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: @Chirag: Shouldnt you be using a RegularExpressionValidator if you want to validate the textbox with regex? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx

Comment: @Dve sorry dear...... Actually you are write, I was missing + at the end and that's the reason it was not working... SORRY AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

You may need to double escape the backslash:

```
[a-zA-Z\\.]+
```